# Create symbolic link excluding some files in a directory

Tags: linux, symlink

Is it possible to symbolic link in Linux excluding some types of files or folders ? For example if I want to symlink a folder "folder1" which has the following files and folders

```
   -folder1  
    -1.json  
    -2.json  
    -3.xml  
    -4.json  
    -5.xml  
    -folder2  
    -folder3
```

Is it possible to exclude the *.xml files and say folder3 when symlinking ? If yes then how ?

Comment: A symlink links to a folder or file. A _single_ folder or file. It does not reference a set of files. What you _can_ do is create a folder and place _many_ simlinks in there, one for each file you want to appear.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this with links.

Comment: Not if you symlink the entire folder. You would need to symlink individual files that you wanted over.  Also this better on something like super user

Comment: You might be able to do something equivalent by creating a user-mode filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. if you create a link to a directory, it will point to the directory itself, not some 'mirror' or duplication of the files inside. so you can't do changes to the linked directory that will not affect the real directory, cause they are practically the same

if the list of files in your directory will not change, you can consider linking each of the files instead of the dir